# How to input free text in visualsearch.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, backbone.js, jquery-ui-autocomplete

As you see on the demo at http://documentcloud.github.io/visualsearch/, we cannot input a text without selecting a facet. Is there a way to input free text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `facetMatches` callback

Answer (score 0):

A Man,

have a look on the demo and give it a bit of testing: when you start typing something not recognized as a facet, it will label your input as 'text' once you hit enter.